# Locate Gemfile error in Bash

Tags: ruby, bash, rubygems, jekyll, bundler

I am working on getting my Jekyll blog configured, and when I ran `bundle exec jekyll serve`, I got the following error:

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

I cannot find the solution to this bug. I have been working on getting Jekyll going, and was getting this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-     3.4.3/.rubocop.yml
```

for `gem install jekyll`, but then I went to root and did `sudo gem install jekyll bundler`

I am running on Ruby version 2.4.0. The tutorials to installing Jekyll are not so helpful because there are so many bugs that come about for these kinds of things. For this particular question, I could not find anything at all that was about Bash.

Comment: How did you installed jekyll? Have you changed your ruby version since?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and their linked pages. Imagine someone handed you your question on a printout and walked away. Could you answer it? Where did you search? What did you try?

Comment: If You have installed the gem with sudo then You need to run the server with sudo too. I totally don't recommend It though. You should have installed the gem on your current user without sudo. Then it would have worked

Comment: So what is the error message of *sudo gem install jekyll bundler*?

Comment: There is none. The issue is `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Answer (score 0):

Remove permission for this file using below command

`$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/.rubocop.yml`

then try

`$ gem install jekyll bundler`

Comment: I did the first command, but then I got an error for the second so I used sudo. That was fine, but I got the same error for `bundle exec jekyll serve`